# How to set auto_ptr to NULL

Tags: c++, stl, struct, binary-tree, auto-ptr

Is there a way to set an auto_ptr to NULL, or the equivalent? For instance, I'm creating a binary tree composed of node objects:

```
struct Node {
    int weight;
    char litteral;
    auto_ptr<Node> childL;
    auto_ptr<Node> childR;
    void set_node(int w, char l, auto_ptr<Node> L, auto_ptr<Node> R){
        weight = w;
        litteral = l;
        childL = L;
        childR = R;
    }
};
```

For an node that is not the parent node, I had planned on doing this:

```
auto_ptr<Node> n(new Node);
(*n).set_node(i->second, i->first, NULL, NULL);
```

This throws an error. Is there any way to set it to NULL, or is there another course of action that would make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::auto_ptr` constructor that takes a pointer is explicit, to help prevent accidentally transferring ownership to an `std::auto_ptr`.  You can pass in two default-constructed `std::auto_ptr` objects:

```
(*n).set_node(i->second, i->first, std::auto_ptr<Node>(), std::auto_ptr<Node>());
```

If the Standard Library implementations you are targeting include `std::unique_ptr`, consider using that instead.  It does not have the problematic copy semantics of `std::auto_ptr`, so `std::auto_ptr` has been deprecated and replaced by `std::unique_ptr`.

`std::unique_ptr` also has a converting constructor that allows implicit conversion from a null pointer constant, so your code passing `NULL` would work just fine if you were using `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use unique_ptr from now on. If I pass an actual auto_ptr to set_node is the ownership given to childL & chilR?

Comment: Yes, when you "copy" a `auto_ptr`, the "old" `auto_ptr` loses ownership (and is reset to null) and the "new" `auto_ptr` gains ownership.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend switching to std::unique_ptr if your compiler toolset supports it (e.g. Visual C++ 10/11, Gcc 4.5? or later), or using boost::scoped_ptr (if you are with Visual C++ 9 or earlier and a recent version of boost), to avoid the fundamental copying semantic issues with std::auto_ptr.

Note: std::unique_ptr is a C++11 feature which may impose extra requirements for choosing your compiler.